# Sqlite INNER JOIN tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 Table : Table1{col11, col12, col13, col14, col15} and Table2{col21, col22}. And 2 Table1.col14 contains Table2.col21(Table1.col14 == Table2.col21).

I want select all columns of Table1. But column Table1.col14 is replace by Table2.col21. 
What query I do ?

Please, help.

Comment: you can use inner join to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Use querybuilder it is awesome.

```
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE1 + " JOIN "
            + TABLE2 + " ON (" + TABLE1 + "." + JOINCOLUMN1 + " = "
            + TABLE2 + "." + JOINCOLUMN2 + ")");
    queryBuilder.appendWhere(TABLE1.COL1 + " = 'SOME VALUE'".....);

    String[] projection = { TABLE1+"."+COL1, TABLE1+"."+COL2...... };

    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
```

you can even get distinct values by using an overloaded ".query(....)" method. Check this [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html)